# Do I need to restrict current to charge a dyson Li-ion battery directly with my photovoltaic system

Tags: current, solar-cell, step-up

I would like to charge my Li-ion battery from Dyson V6 vacuum cleaner with my solar system/controller (12V output voltage) with a step up converter 26.1V/3A. I already charge my apple computers and ipad pros, and all the other electronic stuff, which are all tolerant to current, as they handle current control themselves. However this one is trickier:

The original dyson poweradapter states 26,1V and 780mA. To step up to 26,1V can be easily achieved, but what about the current? My current step up module limits current to 3A. Do I need to limit the current somehow?

I appreciate any feedback. Would it be safe if I step up to 26,1V e.g. with a maximum of 1A only? Or do I need to fit the exact data stated by the original poweradapter?

Kind regards,
Alex

Comment: I just checked. The Li-ion pack comes equipped with a circuit control inside. But I do not know what it does. May I be wrong, that charging with 1A won`t do any harm?

Comment: if your source can provide 3A, and you only need 0.78A, what's the problem? Amps need to be _higher_ on the source than the load, whereas voltages must match closely.

Comment: You do not know if the li-ion pack has a charging logic and limits current. Dyson answered today, their powersuply will smart handle this, not the li-ion electronic build in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that any voltage source, including your step-up converter, only tries to supply the output voltage, it is up to the circuit it's connected to (your Li-ion pack in this example) to determine what current will flow. E.g., if it's an open circuit, the current drawn will be 0; if it is a resistor, then you can apply Ohm's law. The current rating (3A in your example) only determines the maximum amount that the voltage source can supply (if the circuit "requests" it), above that it may fail to work, overheat, etc.

In your case, the best way to see if everything looks normal is to apply those 26.1V from the step-up, and check what the current is with a multimeter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fewXxc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you're measuring 780 mA or less, then it's all good.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the V6, but the Dyson V7 has a protection circuit that trips if you try to charge the battery too fast. The vacuum relies on the power supply to be current-limited: if, for example, you connect the vacuum to a bench-top 26V power supply, it won't charge - it'll draw a bunch of current for a fraction of a second and then stop, with the LED on the battery pack blinking red.

The V7 comes with a 750mA charger, but the protection circuit seems to kick in at about 1.25A. I've managed to reduce the charge time by replacing the 26V/750mA AC Adapter with a current-limited supply set to 26V / 1.25A.

Comment: This post is good but does not answer the question. Can you edit your answer and focus on answering the question?

Comment: OP is asking if charging the battery at 26.1V (limited to 3A) is too much power, and DanX2 is saying the official charger is limited to 750mA, and the Dyson's protection circuit kicks in at 1.25A. In other words, yes, 26.1V @ 3A is too much, and yes, the current form the supply will need to be limited. This is an excellent answer and should be picked as the solution.